# Python List Transpose

Tags: python-3.x

I need to transpose the following python list.

```
`data = (
 ['1002','1','10'],
 ['1002','2','20'],
 ['1002','3','30'],
 ['1004','1','30'],
 ['1004','2','40'],
 ['1004','3','60'])`
```

Need to convert as

```
`(['1002'],['1','2','3'],['10','20','30'],
  ['1004'],['1','2','3'],['30','40','60']) `
```

I tried python nested list comprehensions like this:

```
`[[row[i] for row in data] for i in range(3)]`
```

It does not work. I get all the values in a single row.

I need to break it up based on the first element of the row.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your list is flat, not nested, so the first thing we'll do is group everything by threes

```
zip(*[iter(data)]*3)
```

then we can make a dictionary that which we will build our list in.

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for a, b, c in zip(*[iter(data)]*3):
    d[a].append(b)
    d[a].append(c)
print([(k,) + tuple(v) for k, v in d.items()])
#[('1002', '1', '10', '2', '20', '3', '30'), ('1004', '1', '30', '2', '40', '3', '60')]
```

Then we just build our output from that dictionary.

EDIT:  given the changes, we'll modify the way we store values in the dict slightly

```
data = (
 ['1002','1','10'],
 ['1002','2','20'],
 ['1002','3','30'],
 ['1004','1','30'],
 ['1004','2','40'],
 ['1004','3','60'])

d = defaultdict(list)

for a, b, c in data:
    d[a].append((b, c))

output = []
for k, v in d.items():
    output.append([k])
    a, b = map(list, zip(*v))
    output.append(a)
    output.append(b)

print(output)
#[['1002'], ['1', '2', '3'], ['10', '20', '30'], ['1004'], ['1', '2', '3'], ['30', '40', '60']]
```

Comment: Sorry. The problem is clearly explained now. Please provide some suggestions.

Comment: It works. However, how do i enumerate the results like this?

Comment: ['1002'], ['1', '2', '3'], ['10', '20', '30']

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if List Comprehensions is mandatory to use.

```
data = ['1002','1','10', '1002','2','20', '1002','3','30', '1004','1','30', '1004','2','40', '1004','3','60']
res = []
for index in range(0,len(data),9):
    res.append(data[index:index + 9])

final = []
for item in res:
    x = []
    for element in item:
        if element not in x:
            x.append(element)
    final.append(x)
print(final)
```

Comment: Comprehensions are not mandatory to use. I just need a way of handling this issue

Comment: But data is a tuple, not a list. Are you asking to convert 'a tuple of lists' to 'a tuple of lists' or 'a list of lists' to 'a list of lists'.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to aggregate by the first element, I would consider using `itertools.groupby` (https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
import itertools

data = [
    ['1002','1','10'],
    ['1002','2','20'],
    ['1002','3','30'],
    ['1004','1','30'],
    ['1004','2','40'],
    ['1004','3','60']]

result = [
    [[key] + list(map(list, zip(*[row[1:] for row in rows])))]
    for key, rows in itertools.groupby(data, lambda row: row[0])
]

print(result)

[[['1002', ['1', '2', '3'], ['10', '20', '30']]], [['1004', ['1', '2', '3'], ['30', '40', '60']]]]
```

Comment: This works. However, how do I access individual elements in this result?

Comment: Ah, I realize now that my output doesn't match exactly what you asked for—I have a row for each different first element. So you'd access using `for row in result`, and then `row[0]` is the first element, `row[1]` is the list of second elements, `row[2]` is the list of third elements.

Comment: how can append the elements to numpy? I need to calculate standard deviation for second and third data sets. When I am trying append them to numpy, i get an error that data needs to be integers

Comment: Ah, yes it looks like you have them as strings, so you'll need to convert the lists with something like `[int(x) for x in list]`.